# How could I use a single UIButton to get a library photo with an image picker and perform a push segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, segue

I am trying to pick an image from the photo library and perform a segue only if the user selects an image. (Does nothing if the user presses cancel)

Is it possible to pack all of this action into one single button press via IBAction?

The issue I am facing with my attempted code is that it tries to perform the push segue right when I press the button, which apparently is at the same time I am trying to access the photo library. I can't figure out how to get the image picker to go first and then have the push segue trigger immediately after, depending on whether an image was picked or the process was canceled.

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)LibraryButton:(id)sender
{
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"takeLibraryPhoto"])
    {
        buffer = modBuffer;
        selectDisplayViewController *secondVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"takeCameraPhoto"])
    {

    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"takeCameraVideo"])
    {

    }
}
- (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"takeLibraryPhoto"])
    {
        //[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        if(modBuffer != NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    /*UIImage *loadImage;
    loadImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    buffer = loadImage;*/
    modBuffer = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

selectDisplayViewController.m

```
@implementation selectDisplayViewController
@synthesize selectDisplayView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    selectDisplayView.image = buffer;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

What my code currently does is... When I load an image, "buffer" of selectDisplayViewController is successfully getting data from "modBuffer", but by then the push segue has already occurred and it returns me to the original view controller that I press the button from. It isn't until I press the button a second time (could also press cancel this time) that it takes me to the other view controller where it displays my image.

I have been struggling with this for many days now. How can I get this to behave more like a sequence where its a step process instead of the push segue happening right away!! :(

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand what's with the down voting. I am a beginner with  iOS and objective C and am asking what is probably an obvious beginner's question. So why?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I completely follow but it sounds like you want to perform the segue after the user selects a picture or presses cancel from the image picker.

If that's the case then you can do that in the delegate methods using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"foo" sender:nil];`

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to do! If the user picks an image, then go to another view and display it. Else if the user cancels the process, then stay at the screen where the button was pressed. Can you elaborate more on what I do with the method you suggested?